# Search Query about phone number in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, phone-number, elasticsearch-query

I have a question about Elasticsearch

I made a search query about the phone number. My plan is that even I don't put the hyphen or bracket, result would show the phone number.

For example,
phone number is (213)234-1111
and
search query is

```
GET _msearch
{ "query": {"fuzzy": { "tel": {"value": "2132341111", "max_expansions" : 100}}}}
```

the result is

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "responses" : [
    {
      "took" : 0,
      "timed_out" : false,
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "skipped" : 0,
        "failed" : 0
      },
      "hits" : {
        "total" : {
          "value" : 0,
          "relation" : "eq"
        },
        "max_score" : null,
        "hits" : [ ]
      },
      "status" : 200
    }
  ]
}
```

I need a help that even I put the number without bracket and hyphen, the result show the real phone number with information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow efficient querying, make sure to index the documents accordingly.

In this example that I just made, I am making sure that phone-numbers are indexed without the hyphens and parenthesis. This allows me to query without using those characters as well.

**Example:**

(1) Create the index:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "\\((\\d+)\\)(\\d+)-(\\d+)",
          "replacement": "$1$2$3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(2) Add a document to the index:

```
POST my_index/doc
{
  "Description": "My phone number is (213)234-1111"
}
```

(3) Query with the original phone number:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Description": "(213)234-1111"
    }
  }
}

(1 result)
```

(4) Query without special characters:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Description": "2132341111"
    }
  }
}

(1 result)
```

**So how did that work?**

By using the [pattern_replace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) char filter, we're stripping away everything but the raw numbers, meaning that "(213)234-1111" is actually stored as "2132341111" whenever we match a phone numbes. Since this pattern_replace is also applied at query time, we can now search both with and without the special characters in the phone number and get a match.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. I have question about it. In my company, 2132341111 is actually stored as (213)234-1111. I cannot see how the company index exactly, but my coworker said the number is stored as (213)234-1111. My team and department doesn't have access or authority about the index or edit it. So, is there a way to search the number without hyphen or bracket?

Comment: In case you can't change the index, I think the easiest thing for you to do would be to do the work on the client instead. Write a regex to transform any range of 10 numbers into (nnn)nnn-nnnn and search for both variations in a should clause. If you care about performance, you should always try to achieve direct matches.

Answer (score 0):

New custom tokeniser : https://github.com/purecloudlabs/elasticsearch-phone

Example:
Input (without a country code): 8177148350

Tokens:

```
tel:8177148350
tel:
8177148350
8
81
817
8177
81771
817714
8177148
81771483
817714835
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35009930)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
PUT phone-numbers
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "digits_only": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "[^\\d]"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "us_phone_number": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original": true,
          "patterns": [
            "1?(1)(\\d*)"
          ]
        },
        "ten_digits_min": {
          "type": "length",
          "min": 10
        },
        "not_empty": {
          "type": "length",
          "min": 1
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "phone_number": {
          "char_filter": "digits_only",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "us_phone_number",
            "ten_digits_min"
          ]
        },
        "phone_number_search" : {
          "char_filter" : "digits_only",
          "tokenizer" : "keyword",
          "filter" : [
            "not_empty"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "phone_number": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer" : "phone_number",
          "search_analyzer" : "phone_number_search"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


POST phone-numbers/_analyze
{
  "text" : "      555 3 2 1  8286",
  "analyzer": "phone_number"
}

POST phone-numbers/_analyze
{
  "text" : "1(855) 555-5344",
  "analyzer": "phone_number"
}

POST phone-numbers/_analyze
{
  "text" : "1(855) 555",
  "analyzer": "phone_number_search"
}
```

For more description : https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/elasticsearch-indexing-of-us-phone-numbers